# Type mismatch in recursive function using Bitbucket API and Playframework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, bitbucket-api

I created a generic function to get from Bitbucket-API (It gives you the data in pages if there is to much data and the next page URL is under "next" in the response).

```
def getAggregatedDataWithNext[T](url: String)(implicit reader: Reads[T]): Future[Seq[T]]= {
    val featureResponse = ws.url(url).withAuth(AuthUserName, AuthPassword, WSAuthScheme.BASIC).addQueryStringParameters("pagelen" -> "100").get()
    featureResponse.map(response => {
      val resJson = response.json
      val tSequence = (resJson \ "values").as[Seq[T]]

      (resJson \ "next").asOpt[String] match {
        case None => tSequence
        case Some(nextUrl) => getAggregatedDataWithNext(nextUrl).flatMap(tSequence ++ _)
      }
    })
  }
```

I get an error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[T]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
```

And IntelliJ gives me this:
[image]

Comment: You want `.map`, not `.flatMap`

Comment: I don't think so and I tried it, and it still does not solves the problem, What is really weird is that if I use 'map' the error is exactly the opposite: 
  " type mismatch;
     found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[T]]
     required: Seq[T]  "

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. Albeit similar :) Your `featureResponse.map` needs to be changed to `.flatMap`. And `case None => tSequence` needs to be `case None => Future.successful(tSequence)`

Comment: You are right. Can you explain why?

Comment: Just look at the [definitions](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/concurrent/Future.html) of `.map` and `.flatMap`, and note the type of the parameter. In one case it is `T => S` and in the other it is `T => Future[S]`. The function you are passing in has to match that type. Looking at the type signatures in scala is often the best way to infer correct. use of a function.  Also [this page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) has some examples on using futures with combinators.

Comment: Where the 'S' comes from? What is type 'S'? What is 'NotInferedS'? I didn't define an 'S' type.

Comment: If you click on the link I suggested above and look up the definitions of `map` and `flatMap`, you will see where the `S` comes from. `NotInferredS` just means that the compiler was unable to infer the actual value for the type parameter `S`